# XSLT How to increment in a Muenchian grouping Transform?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a grouping transform that I would like to include a count/increment in. The transform groups values if assigned a grouping. The values are file locations which the transform uses to join together so the content is output as one. If there is no grouping assigned the transform uses the value to to get the file content without appending it to anything.

XSLT:

```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
       <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
       <xsl:key name="modules" match="module[@group]" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', @group)"/>

       <xsl:template match="root">
           <AllSections>
               <xsl:apply-templates />
           </AllSections>
       </xsl:template>

       <!-- NON GROUPED PART -->
       <xsl:template match="module[not(@group)]">
              <page>
               <content>
                <xsl:variable name="var">
                 <xsl:value-of select="comp"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:copy-of select="document(concat('../myfile/', string($var)))"/>
               </content>
             </page>
       </xsl:template>

       <!--GROUPED PART -->
       <xsl:template match="module[@group][generate-id() = generate-id(key('modules', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @group))[1])]">
           <xsl:variable name="modules" select="key('modules', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @group))"/>
           <page>
               <content>
                <xsl:for-each select="$modules/comp">
                 <xsl:copy-of select="document(concat('../myfile/', .))"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
               </content>

           </page>
       </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="module"/>

       <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
           <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
           </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

INPUT:

```
    <root>
        <section>
            <subsection>
                <module>
                    <comp>aaa.html</comp>
                </module>
                <module group='group01'>
                    <comp>bbb.html</comp>
                </module>
                <module group='group01'>
                    <comp>ccc.html</comp>
                </module>
                <module>
                    <comp>ddd.html</comp>
                </module>
                <module>
                    <comp>eee.html</comp>
                </module>
            </subsection>
        </section>
        <section>
            <subsection>
                <module group ="group02">
                    <comp>fff.html</comp>
                </module>
                <module group ="group02">
                    <comp>ggg.html</comp>
                </module>
                <module>
                    <comp>hhh.html</comp>
                </module>
                <module group ="group03">
                    <comp>iii.html</comp>
                </module>
                <module group ="group03">
                    <comp>jjj.html</comp>
                </module>
            </subsection>
            <subsection>
                <module group ="group04">
                    <comp>kkk.html</comp>
                </module>
                <module group ="group04">
                    <comp>lll.html</comp>
                </module>
                <module group ="group05">
                    <comp>mmm.html</comp>
                </module>
                <module group ="group05">
                    <comp>nnn.html</comp>
                </module>
                <module group ="group06">
                    <comp>ooo.html</comp>
                </module>
                <module group ="group06">
                    <comp>ppp.html/comp>
                </module>
                <module>
                    <comp>qqq.html</comp>
                </module>
            </subsection>
        </section>
    </root>
```

OUTPUT Sample:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <AllSections>   
        <section>        
            <subsection>            
                <page>
                    <content>
                        CONTENT FROM aaa.html
                    </content>
                </page>            
                <page>
                    <content>
                        CONTENT FROM bbb.html
                        CONTENT FROM ccc.html
                    </content>
                </page>           
                <page>
                    <content>
                        CONTENT FROM ddd.html
                    </content>
                </page>           
                <page>
                    <content>
                        CONTENT FROM eee.html
                    </content>
                </page>            
            </subsection>       
        </section>    
        <section>       
            <subsection>  
                <page>
                    <content>
                        CONTENT FROM fff.html
                        CONTENT FROM ggg.html
                    </content>
                </page>           
                <page>
                    <content>
                        CONTENT FROM hhh.html
                    </content>
                </page>            
                <page>
                    <content>
                        CONTENT FROM iii.html
                        CONTENT FROM jjj.html
                    </content>
                </page>         
            </subsection>        
            <subsection>            
                <page>
                    <content>
                        CONTENT FROM kkk.html
                        CONTENT FROM lll.html
                    </content>
                </page>           
                <page>
                    <content>
                        CONTENT FROM mmm.html
                        CONTENT FROM nnn.html
                    </content>
                </page>           
                <page>
                    <content>
                        CONTENT FROM ooo.html
                        CONTENT FROM ppp.html
                    </content>
                </page>           
                <page>
                    <content>
                        CONTENT FROM qqq.html
                    </content>
                </page>           
            </subsection>       
        </section>    
    </AllSections>
```

What I'm trying to do is put a counter in for the total pages, see below, with respect to section AND subsection AND assigning the increment to . I've tried param but it requires a recursion template? which if I put in just sem to break the rest of the transform. Is there not a 'loop' already created when using a template?

Output trying to get:

```
   <AllSections>   
        <section>        
            <subsection>            
                <page>
                    <content>
                        CONTENT FROM aaa.html
                    </content>
                    <page_no>1</page_no>
                </page>            
                <page>
                    <content>
                        CONTENT FROM bbb.html
                        CONTENT FROM ccc.html
                    </content>
                    <page_no>2</page_no>
                </page>           
                <page>
                    <content>
                        CONTENT FROM ddd.html
                    </content>
                    <page_no>3</page_no>
                </page>           
                <page>
                    <content>
                        CONTENT FROM eee.html
                    </content>
                    <page_no>4</page_no>
                </page>                   
                <subscection_total_pages>4</subscection_total_pages>
            </subsection>  
            <scection_total_pages>4</scection_total_pages>
        </section>    
        <section>       
            <subsection>  
                <page>
                    <content>
                        CONTENT FROM fff.html
                        CONTENT FROM ggg.html
                    </content>
                    <page_no>1</page_no>
                </page>           
                <page>
                    <content>
                        CONTENT FROM hhh.html
                    </content>
                    <page_no>2</page_no>
                </page>            
                <page>
                    <content>
                        CONTENT FROM iii.html
                        CONTENT FROM jjj.html
                    </content>
                    <page_no>3</page_no>
                </page>
                <subscection_total_pages>3</subscection_total_pages>
            </subsection>        
            <subsection>            
                <page>
                    <content>
                        CONTENT FROM kkk.html
                        CONTENT FROM lll.html
                    </content>
                    <page_no>1</page_no>
                </page>           
                <page>
                    <content>
                        CONTENT FROM mmm.html
                        CONTENT FROM nnn.html
                    </content>
                    <page_no>2</page_no>
                </page>           
                <page>
                    <content>
                        CONTENT FROM ooo.html
                        CONTENT FROM ppp.html
                    </content>
                    <page_no>3</page_no>
                </page>           
                <page>
                    <content>
                        CONTENT FROM qqq.html
                    </content>
                    <page_no>4</page_no>
                </page>
                <subscection_total_pages>4</subscection_total_pages>
            </subsection>
            <scection_total_pages>7</scection_total_pages>
        </section>    
    </AllSections>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
       <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
       <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

       <xsl:key name="modules" match="module[@group]" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', @group)"/>

       <xsl:template match="root">
           <AllSections>
               <xsl:apply-templates />
           </AllSections>
       </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="section">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="subsection"/>
           <section_total_pages>
             <xsl:value-of select="
             count(subsection/module[not(@group)]) + 
             count(subsection/module[@group][generate-id() = generate-id(key('modules', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @group))[1])])"/>
           </section_total_pages>
         </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="subsection">
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="groups" select="module[not(@group)] | module[@group][generate-id() = generate-id(key('modules', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @group))[1])]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$groups"/>
            <subsection_total_pages>
              <xsl:value-of select="count($groups)"/>
            </subsection_total_pages>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>


       <!-- NON GROUPED PART -->
       <xsl:template match="module[not(@group)]">
              <page>
               <content>
                <xsl:copy-of select="document(concat('../myfile/', comp))"/>
               </content>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="page-no"/>
             </page>
       </xsl:template>

       <!--GROUPED PART -->
       <xsl:template match="module[@group]">
           <xsl:variable name="modules" select="key('modules', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @group))"/>
           <page>
               <content>
                <xsl:for-each select="$modules/comp">
                  <xsl:copy-of select="document(concat('../myfile/', .))"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
               </content>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="page-no"/>
           </page>
       </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="module" mode="page-no">
               <page_no>
                 <xsl:number count="module[not(@group)] | module[@group][generate-id() = generate-id(key('modules', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @group))[1])]"/>
               </page_no>
       </xsl:template>


       <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
           <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
           </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I apply above code with Saxon 6.5.5 to the input

```
<root>
    <section>
        <subsection>
            <module>
                <comp>aaa.html</comp>
            </module>
            <module group='group01'>
                <comp>bbb.html</comp>
            </module>
            <module group='group01'>
                <comp>ccc.html</comp>
            </module>
            <module>
                <comp>ddd.html</comp>
            </module>
            <module>
                <comp>eee.html</comp>
            </module>
        </subsection>
    </section>
    <section>
        <subsection>
            <module group ="group02">
                <comp>fff.html</comp>
            </module>
            <module group ="group02">
                <comp>ggg.html</comp>
            </module>
            <module>
                <comp>hhh.html</comp>
            </module>
            <module group ="group03">
                <comp>iii.html</comp>
            </module>
            <module group ="group03">
                <comp>jjj.html</comp>
            </module>
        </subsection>
        <subsection>
            <module group ="group04">
                <comp>kkk.html</comp>
            </module>
            <module group ="group04">
                <comp>lll.html</comp>
            </module>
            <module group ="group05">
                <comp>mmm.html</comp>
            </module>
            <module group ="group05">
                <comp>nnn.html</comp>
            </module>
            <module group ="group06">
                <comp>ooo.html</comp>
            </module>
            <module group ="group06">
                <comp>ppp.html</comp>
            </module>
            <module>
                <comp>qqq.html</comp>
            </module>
        </subsection>
    </section>
</root>
```

I get the result

```
<AllSections>
   <section>
      <subsection>
         <page>
            <content/>
            <page_no>1</page_no>
         </page>
         <page>
            <content/>
            <page_no>2</page_no>
         </page>
         <page>
            <content/>
            <page_no>3</page_no>
         </page>
         <page>
            <content/>
            <page_no>4</page_no>
         </page>
         <subsection_total_pages>4</subsection_total_pages>
      </subsection>
      <section_total_pages>4</section_total_pages>
   </section>
   <section>
      <subsection>
         <page>
            <content/>
            <page_no>1</page_no>
         </page>
         <page>
            <content/>
            <page_no>2</page_no>
         </page>
         <page>
            <content/>
            <page_no>3</page_no>
         </page>
         <subsection_total_pages>3</subsection_total_pages>
      </subsection>
      <subsection>
         <page>
            <content/>
            <page_no>1</page_no>
         </page>
         <page>
            <content/>
            <page_no>2</page_no>
         </page>
         <page>
            <content/>
            <page_no>3</page_no>
         </page>
         <page>
            <content/>
            <page_no>4</page_no>
         </page>
         <subsection_total_pages>4</subsection_total_pages>
      </subsection>
      <section_total_pages>7</section_total_pages>
   </section>
</AllSections>
```

which seems to have the right total numbers. Obviously I don't have those files to be pulled in so the content is all missing.

Answer (score 0):

**This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet...**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  

<xsl:key name="kModules" match="module[@group]" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', @group)"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <AllSections>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </AllSections>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    <section_total_pages><xsl:number
       value="count(subsection/module[ not(@group) or 
  (generate-id()=generate-id( key('kModules',concat(generate-id(..),'|',@group))[1]))])"/>
    </section_total_pages> 
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="subsection">
  <xsl:variable name="subsect-id" select="concat(generate-id(),'|')" />
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="page-heads"
    select="module[ not(@group) or 
            (generate-id()=generate-id( key('kModules',concat($subsect-id, @group))[1]))]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="
      @*| node()[not(self::module)] | $page-heads"/>
    <subsection_total_pages><xsl:number value="count($page-heads)"/></subsection_total_pages>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="module">
  <xsl:variable name="subsect-id" select="concat(generate-id(..),'|')" />
  <page>
   <content>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kModules',concat($subsect-id, @group))/comp | comp" />
   </content>
   <page_no><xsl:number count="module[not(@group) or 
     (generate-id() =
      generate-id( key('kModules',concat($subsect-id, @group))[1]))]"/></page_no>  
  </page>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comp">
  <!-- Change this sequence constructor to do your document pulling bit. -->
  <xsl:comment>content from <xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...when applied to the given sample input, yields...**

```
<AllSections>
  <section>
    <subsection>
      <page>
        <content>
          <!--content from aaa.html-->
        </content>
        <page_no>1</page_no>
      </page>
      <page>
        <content>
          <!--content from bbb.html-->
          <!--content from ccc.html-->
        </content>
        <page_no>2</page_no>
      </page>
      <page>
        <content>
          <!--content from ddd.html-->
        </content>
        <page_no>3</page_no>
      </page>
      <page>
        <content>
          <!--content from eee.html-->
        </content>
        <page_no>4</page_no>
      </page>
      <subsection_total_pages>4</subsection_total_pages>
    </subsection>
    <section_total_pages>4</section_total_pages>
  </section>
  <section>
    <subsection>
      <page>
        <content>
          <!--content from fff.html-->
          <!--content from ggg.html-->
        </content>
        <page_no>1</page_no>
      </page>
      <page>
        <content>
          <!--content from hhh.html-->
        </content>
        <page_no>2</page_no>
      </page>
      <page>
        <content>
          <!--content from iii.html-->
          <!--content from jjj.html-->
        </content>
        <page_no>3</page_no>
      </page>
      <subsection_total_pages>3</subsection_total_pages>
    </subsection>
    <subsection>
      <page>
        <content>
          <!--content from kkk.html-->
          <!--content from lll.html-->
        </content>
        <page_no>1</page_no>
      </page>
      <page>
        <content>
          <!--content from mmm.html-->
          <!--content from nnn.html-->
        </content>
        <page_no>2</page_no>
      </page>
      <page>
        <content>
          <!--content from ooo.html-->
          <!--content from ppp.html-->
        </content>
        <page_no>3</page_no>
      </page>
      <page>
        <content>
          <!--content from qqq.html-->
        </content>
        <page_no>4</page_no>
      </page>
      <subsection_total_pages>4</subsection_total_pages>
    </subsection>
    <section_total_pages>7</section_total_pages>
  </section>
</AllSections>
```

### Notes

1. Template matching `comp` is as it is for testing purposes. For production purposes change as required, using the document() function as you have done.
2. I would avoid putting Muenchian tests in match conditions. That is going to be really painful as template match tests are tested often.
3. The nub of your problem is solved by `xsl:number` with a `count` attribute. This is the main raison d'etre for xsl:number. (Congrats to Martin with his first post and correct use of that.)
4. There was a missing angle bracket in your sample input.
5. I assumed that `subscection_total_pages` was meant to be spelt subsection_total_pages, and similar for `scection_total_pages`.

### Interesting alternative solution

Instead of splitting the handling of `module` into two cases, you could instead invent a key valid for all `modules`, where, if the `group` attribute was absent, the key value was a unique one to that one. The following alternative solution adopting such an approach, assumes that the generate-id() function will never include a double `@` character.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  

<xsl:key name="kModules" match="module" use="
  concat(generate-id(..),'|',
  substring-before( concat( generate-id(),'@',@group,'@',generate-id()), '@@' ),
  @group)"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <AllSections>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </AllSections>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    <section_total_pages><xsl:number
       value="count(subsection/module[  
  (generate-id()=generate-id( key('kModules',
        concat(generate-id(..),'|',
  substring-before( concat( generate-id(),'@',@group,'@',generate-id()), '@@' ),
  @group))[1]))])"/>
    </section_total_pages> 
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="subsection">
  <xsl:variable name="subsect-id" select="concat(generate-id(),'|')" />
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="page-heads"
    select="module[ 
            (generate-id()=generate-id( key('kModules',concat(generate-id(..),'|',
  substring-before( concat( generate-id(),'@',@group,'@',generate-id()), '@@' ),@group))[1]))]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*| node()[not(self::module)] | $page-heads"/>
    <subsection_total_pages><xsl:number value="count($page-heads)"/></subsection_total_pages>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="module">
  <xsl:variable name="subsect-id" select="concat(generate-id(..),'|')" />
  <page>
   <content>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kModules',concat(generate-id(..),'|',
  substring-before( concat( generate-id(),'@',@group,'@',generate-id()), '@@' ),
  @group))/comp" />
   </content>
   <page_no><xsl:number count="module[
     (generate-id()=generate-id( key('kModules',concat(generate-id(..),'|',
  substring-before( concat( generate-id(),'@',@group,'@',generate-id()), '@@' ),
  @group))[1]))]"/></page_no>  
  </page>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comp">
  <!-- Change this sequence constructor to do your document pulling bit. -->
  <xsl:comment>content from <xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### How does the alternative solution work?

Consider the important part of the Xpath expression used in the key `value` value

```
concat(
  substring-before(
    concat( generate-id(), '@' ,@group, '@', generate-id()),
    '@@' ),
  @group
  )
```

If @group is absent or empty, then this is equivalent to...

```
concat(
  substring-before(
    concat( generate-id(), '@@', generate-id()),
    '@@' ),
  @group
  )
```

... or ...

```
concat( generate-id(), @group)
```

... or ...

```
generate-id()
```

... which is unique for each node, which is what we want.

But if @group is not empty, then this is equivalent to...

```
concat(
  '',
  @group
  )
```

... or ...

```
@group
```

Allowing modules with group attribute to be grouped together.